# Dynamics "rollapply" in R

Tags: r, data.table, rollapply

I am thinking of getting max of (N-1) rows by group in R (but not including the current row). Not sure how should I start with since each group has dynamics number of rows. For example:

[image: Example of what I want]

Thanks =)

Comment: It would be good if you could change the picture into text. That way when the imgur link goes away, your question will still be useful to others.

Comment: I don't think the link is likely to go away since SO provides such links itself but the responders to the question will have to manually re-type in the input if it is not given in text form.

Answer (score 3):

Using `DF` defined reproducibly in the Note at the end, we can use `rollapply` to apply `max` taking the maximum of all prior values where specifying a width of  `list(-seq(.N))` to `rollapply` means to use offsets -1, -2, ..., -.N .  `partial=TRUE` says to use whatever number of values are available among the specified offsets even if some of the offsets are not available. Finally run it on each group using `by=`.

This solution uses `rollapply` and data.table, as requested, and involves direct specification of which offsets to use as opposed to shifting or lagging.

We could change `max` to `min`, `sum`, `mean`, `median` or anything else that is appropriate if we wanted those.  If we wanted to change this to just find the maximum of the prior k values then we could replace `-seq(.N)` with `-seq(k)`.

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

DT <- as.data.table(DF)
DT[, max := rollapply(Count, list(-seq(.N)), max, partial = TRUE, fill = NA), by = Group]
```

giving:

```
> DT
   Group Count max
1:     A    23  NA
2:     A    12  23
3:     A   145  23
4:     B   123  NA
5:     B    34 123
6:     B   456 123
7:     B   555 456
```

### Note

The input `DF` in reproducible form is:

```
DF <- data.frame(Group = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
                 Count = c(23, 12, 145, 123, 34, 456, 555))
```

### Update

Fixed original and updated it with a shorter solution and one which uses data.table as per data.table tag on question.

Comment: Nice solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution with the `data.table`-package and the `cummax` and `shift` functions:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lagged_max := shift(cummax(Count)), by = Group][]
```

which gives:

> ```
> > df
>    Group Count lagged_max
> 1:     A    23         NA
> 2:     A    12         23
> 3:     A   145         23
> 4:     B   123         NA
> 5:     B    34        123
> 6:     B   456        123
> 7:     B   555        456
> ```

What this does:

- `setDT(df)` converts the dataframe `df` to a `data.table`.
- `cummax(Count)` gets the cumulative maximum of `Count`.
- With `shift` the result is shifted one position upward because the default values for the `n`, `type` & `fill` parameters are `1L`, `lag` an `NA` respectively, Written in full it is: `shift(cummax(Count), n = 1L, type = 'lag', fill = NA)`.

---

The same logic in base R:

```
transform(df, lagged_max = ave(Count, Group, FUN = function(x) c(NA, head(cummax(x), -1))))
```

---

Or with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  mutate(lagged_max = lag(cummax(Count)))
```

---

Used data:

```
df <- data.frame(Group = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
                 Count = c(23, 12, 145, 123, 34, 456, 555))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution using `dplyr::lag`:

```
# Sample data
df <- data.frame(
    Group = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
    Count = c(23, 12, 145, 123, 34, 456, 555))

library(tidyverse);
df %>%
    group_by(Group) %>%
    mutate(
        n1 = lag(Count, 1),
        n2 = lag(Count, 2),
        max = ifelse(!is.na(n2) & !is.na(n1) & n2 > n1, n2, n1)) %>%
    select(-n1, -n2)
## A tibble: 7 x 3
## Groups:   Group [2]
#  Group Count   max
#  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 A       23.   NA
#2 A       12.   23.
#3 A      145.   23.
#4 B      123.   NA
#5 B       34.  123.
#6 B      456.  123.
#7 B      555.  456.
```

Comment: Your results do not match the results in the question.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Thanks and fixed.